# How To Handle Covariance Limitations?

Tags: c#, covariance

This is basically a design problem.

My class structure is as follows:

```
Interface IA
interface IB<T> where T : IA
abstract class AC<T> : IB<T>

class D : IA
class E : IA
class F : AC<D>
class G : AC<E>
```

Now, I have a method in AC whose signature is:

```
void foo(IB<IA> param)
```

And I want to call it from F like this:

```
foo(new G())
```

I know about the limitation of covariance and contravariance, and I know the language doesn't allow it. Also, I can't set `IB<out T>`.

My question  is, what is the correct way to handle such a situation design-wise?

Comment: Can you be specific about why you can't set `IB<out T>`?

Comment: (I suspect this is a duplicate question, btw - but it's hard to work out how I'd search for it...)

Comment: @MatthewWatson According to the limitations of Covariance, I can't set <out T> either when T is used in the where limitation, or used as a parameter for a method.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997386(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: @JonSkeet It seemed like a question which must have been asked before, but i couldn't find it..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It sounds like you need to make the `Foo` method generic:

```
void Foo<T>(IB<T> param) where T : IA
```

At that point, `Foo(new G())` would be implicitly `Foo<E>(new G())`.